# Let $X$ be a projective variety. Then is the collection of $k$ planes in $X$ a closed subset of the Grassmanian?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-verification

I think I have found an argument, but I am curious about other ways to solve this question. In particular, my approach is very linear algebraic (which is not a bad thing!), but I am wondering if there is some "pure thought" way to arrive at this conclusion. (Provided it is true, and I didn't make a mistake. It seems geometrically very plausible, just given that if I am moving some planes around in a closed set, the limits of these planes should still be in the closed set.)

When writing this up I thought of a second argument that is maybe closer to the flavor I want, which I have written below my first argument (it is in the second box). I would be happy if a trained eye could look at that one.

Is there a general machine or method that will translate a statement involving the symbol $\subseteq$ and varieties into some polynomials?

Answer (score 0):

Argument 1:

Cover the Grassmanian $G$ with the charts $U_i \cong Hom(V_i,W_i)$ associating a plane $E$ transversal to $W_i$ to the matrix $M_E$ that describes $E$ as a graph of a linear function from $V_i \in G$ to complementary (transversal) plane $W_i$. Suppose that $X$ is cut out by polynomials $f_j$. Then the condition that $X$ contains a plane $E \in U_i$ is the condition that for each $j$, $f_j \circ M^i_E$ vanishes along $V_i$. But the condition that a polynomial vanishes along a closed subset of $P^k$ is algebraic in the coefficients of that polynomial (see lemma below). Thus we are given algebraic conditions in the coefficients of $f_j$ and $M^i_E$ and, since the $f_j$ are fixed, this gives algebraic conditions on $U_i$. But we have shown that there is an open cover on which the set of planes in $X$ is closed, hence it is closed.

Lemma:

The collection of degree $d$ polynomials whose zero loci contains an projective algebraic set $Y$ is a closed subset of $P^N$.

$I(Y) = (g_1, \ldots, g_n)$, so $Z(f) \supset X$ iff $f \in I(Y)$. We look at just the polynomials $g_i$ of degree $\leq d$, and try to find a row vector $A$ consisting of polynomials of complementary ($d - \deg g_i$) degree, so that $f = A (g_1, \ldots, g_n)$ (I think this is where I am using homogeneity, but it is not clear to me how this breaks if I drop it). Writing out everything in terms of monomials, this asks: when given some fixed collection of vectors $v_i$, is the condition that a new vector $v$ be a linear combination of the previous vectors algebraic in the coefficients of $v$? But of course this just asks that $v$ is in the span of the $v_i$, which is a subspace, hence closed.

---

Argument 2:

Let $M$ be the space of $r+1$ by $n+1$ matrices of maximal rank, and consider the surjective map $M \to G(r,n)$ sending a matrix to its image and then to the corresponding point in the Grassmanian. This map is algebraic, and we factor it through the projectivation to get $f: \mathbb{P}(M) \to G(r,n)$, which is a fibration by $PGL_k(r)$ (precomposition by automorphisms) and so implies that $f$ is a proper map. So we only have to show that set of $M$ whose image lies in $X$ is algebraic and a cone through the origin, and it will follow that the image in $G(r,n)$ is algebraic. But a matrix $E \in M$ has image in $X$ iff $f_i \circ E = 0$ for all $i$, and for each $i$ this gives a collection of algebraic conditions on the entries of $E$. These algebraic conditions are homogeneous because the $f_i$ are homogeneous polynomials - and so when we substitute $x_i = L_i(y_0, \ldots, y_r)$ and collect monomials, we get a bunch of homogeneous equations in the coefficients of the $L_i$.